How to hide custom buttons in jqgrid ^3.4.4
I am using jqgrid 3.4.4 version, I want to hide few buttons on select row, but the problem is if I add id or title in navButtonAdd, it doesn't work. So I cannot hide them using the id/title.
Is there any other way to achieve this ? (I know this works in later versions)
.navButtonAdd('#pager',{
      caption:"", 
      buttonimg:"<%=ctx%>/images/printer.gif",
      id: "print_btn_id", //not working
      title:"Print",  // not working
      onClickButton: function(){}
      });

